# What is MAMD in a user agent string?

Tags: user-agent

In this user agent string:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; **MAMD**; BRI/2)

what is the MAMD from? It's the only piece I can't reproduce. http://user-agent-string.info tells me it's an "unknown fragment."

Answer (score 0):

The information at [What Is My Browser](http://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/unknown-user-agent-fragments) suggests that it's an OEM identifier - it has something to do with a version of Internet Explorer distributed by a computer manufacturer. The exact meaning of "MAMD" isn't clear, though.

Answer (score 0):

It says [here](https://user-agents.me/windows-oem-manufacturer-list) that's the OEM identifier for [Medion](http://www.medion.com/)